# Call header and footer on login page

Tags: wp-login-form

Is there a way to call theme header and footer on the default login/register page? I understand that we can easily make a custom login page still asking.

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible not call header and footer in wp-login.php, but you can customize it if you want (adding your logo, custom CSS and scripts, etc). What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: hmm.. I understood that. Actually I did not want to create custom login page, custom reset password page. Instead I wanted to just call header and footer on the default login page and then it will look much and being a part of the site. Now I think this is the only option left.

Comment: It is also possible to render login form within page template. There are some nice plugins for that.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at wp-login.php there are two interesting functions called `login_header()` and `login_footer()`. The footer one has a `login_footer` action which runs before the body tag is closed, so if you're looking to add extra markup it can go there. The `login_header()` function doesn't have a convenient action to render more markup, so the simple answer to your question is **no**.

That said, even if they both ran convenient actions, it would likely all fall apart if you simply added your theme's `get_header()` and `get_footer()` templates, because both assume there is no other markup before and after they're called, which is not the case for wp-login.php. So for this to work, wp-login.php would need some rearchitecting to make it theme-aware with sane defaults.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. So, I better create custom templates for login and reset passwords.